# How do I include extra assemblies in my package when publishing a project?

Tags: .net, visual-studio, msbuild, msdeploy

The .dlls are all in the project's bin folder when packaging happens, though they get there by complicated means I'd rather not get into. I just need to get them into the package. Looking at the build output, I'm guessing I need to edit the PackageUsingManifest step, though I'm not sure how.

Comment: Simple set the property "Copy Local" to true, of all dll you want to include. To see the DLL and properties, select the project and click "show all files". They are under the tag "references".

Comment: That's why I meant by complicated means - these assemblies aren't actually referenced by this project.

Answer (score 0):

A package is an atomic deliverable that is self-sufficient.
This is intended to be easily distributed and parametrized. 
So if you are using package with external dependencies you probably just want to use a simple zip file instead of the deploy packaging functionality.

Therefore if you have other assemblies referenced you may want to create a solution libs folder where you will store external references and link your appropriate projects with those references.
Your dll will then all be available in your output folder if you set theme to be `'Copy Local = true'`

Then you will be able to package you assembly (project) with msbuild (target package).
`msbuild /t:package MyProject\MyProject.csproj` or `msbuild /t:package MySolution.sln`